# Redirecting bash script output to a folder

Tags: bash, file

I have two directories from which I am extracting specific columns from two files and saving them to a new file:

```
shopt -s nullglob
a_files=(/path/to/a_files/*.csv)
b_files=(/path/to/b_files/*.csv)
out_dir=(/path/to/output/folder)

for ((i=0; i<"${#a_files[@]}"; i++)); do
    paste -d, <(cut "${a_files[i]}" -d, -f1-6) \
              <(cut "${b_files[i]}" -d, -f7-) > c_file"$i".csv

done
```

The code works, but I would like the output files to be saved in the output directory `out_dir`and to have the file names of the `a_files`

I have tried to use `>"out_dir/$a_files"` but I get the error "No such files or directories".

How can redirect the output files to a directory?

I am using Linux Ubuntu.

Update:
`a_files` and `b_files` have the same number of rows but they exist in different folders.

Comment: Does the directory exist yet? Redirection will create files, but not directories.

Comment: Also, are `a_files` and `b_files` really the same? If so, you don't need both of them, do you?

Comment: `$a_files` is the same as `${a_files[0]}`, and it's a full path like `/path/to/files/foo.csv`, not just `foo.csv`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I assume that OP's use of '/path/to/files' can be read as an obfuscation of his actual paths, not an indicator that a_files and b_files are actually in the same directory

Comment: ...however, that obfuscation prevents anyone else from reproducing the problem, making the question run afoul of [mcve] rules. Code in a question should be the shortest thing that can be successfully tested to reproduce the problem in all essential aspects *before* that question is asked.

Comment: (In an ideal world, a reproducer would contain commands to *create* A, B and output directories, and a few CSV files inside each, such that the problem can be reproduced or an answer tested just by copying and pasting direct to a command line).

Comment: @Buzz : Did  you mean `b_files=(/different_path/to/files/*.csv)`? If so, please update your Q, if not, see comments above ;-). Good luck.

Comment: The a_files and b_files are in different folders. I have duly updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a_files=(/path/to/files/*.csv)
b_files=(/path/to/files/*.csv)
out_dir="/path/to/output/folder"

# create the output directory
mkdir -p "$out_dir"
for ((i=0; i<"${#a_files[@]}"; i++)); do
    # move the output to "$out_dir" with the filename the same as in ${a_files[i]}
    paste -d, <(cut "${a_files[i]}" -d, -f1-6) <(cut "${b_files[i]}" -d, -f7-) \
      > "$out_dir"/"$(basename "${a_files[i]}")"
done
```

But this so much feels for me like a job for xargs, but that's just me:

```
a_path="/path/to/files/*.csv"
b_path="/path/to/files/*.csv"
out_dir="/path/to/output/folder"

join -z <(printf "%s\0" $a_path) <(printf "%s\0" $b_path) | xargs -0 -n2 sh -c 'paste -d, <(cut "$1" -d, -f1-6) <(cut "$2" -d, -f7-) > '"$out_dir"'/"$(basename "$1")"' --
```

Comment: interesting use of `xargs`, but the `join -z` solution seems like a maintenance headache ;-) Just MHO. Good luck to all.

Comment: This solves my problem. The xargs option works too but I have settled for the first answer. Thanks all round.